# Configuring popup in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show a popup message to the user, but am having trouble finding the documentation to do this.

Here is how I can create an alert:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wait" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this.  This action cannot be undone" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[alert show];
```

How would I create a popup that just says:

```
"Thanks for signing up!"
[ OK ]
```

Comment: What iOS version are you doing this on? In iOS8 `UIAlertView`s have been deprecated in favor of `UIAlertController` try searching for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre `iOS 8` using the `UIAlertView` would be like

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                message:@"Thanks for signing up" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
```

make sure to add the `UIAlertViewDelegate` the documentation for `UIAlertView` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) and post `iOS 8` using `UIAlertController` would be like

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                 message:@"Thanks for signing up"
                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                               //Do some thing here
                                               [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                           }];
[alert addAction:ok];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The `UIAlertController` documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@""
                                                     message:@"Thanks for signing up!"
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do it like this

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thanks for signing up!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```